# Angular4 search filter functionality on Entire table

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms, angular2-filtering

Here i Implemented small search filter on a table But My Requirement is its should search whole the table not within the page?

**search**

```
<label> Search FRom Table:</label> <input (change)="someval($event.target.value)">          


someval(value){
   let data=JSON.stringify(value);
   console.log(data.length);
   this.auction.find(e=>e.uniqueid=data);
   this.GetDashBoardData();
}
GetDashBoardData(){
    var somedata= this.globalService.getBasicInfoData();
    this.auctionRequest = {    
      "loginId": this.userdata.LoginID
    }; 
    return this.httpService.dashbordTheUser2(this.auctionRequest).subscribe((response) => {
      this.auction = response.data;
}
```

Here i change slight like When i enter some text in textbox its fing in Array of **This.auction**  but i dont know how can i bind this in table

```
<tr *ngFor="let value of pagedItems">
                     <td>{{value.name}}</td>
```

Comment: What's the output in your console if you put this line in your filter before return? `console.log('result: ', customers.filter(customer => customer.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1));`

Comment: @DiabolicWords  its display 1st Record

Comment: The answer of Krishna Rathore looks promising. Have you tried it?

Comment: no this is shiwing filtering as per oaging

Comment: Sorry, but I have no further idea.

Comment: @DiabolicWords could u plz re check my code it was just updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this solutuion

I have create a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-search-filter-functionality-on-entire-table?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch.pipe.ts)

> Search Pipe

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!args) {
      return value;
    }
    return value.filter((val) => {
      let rVal = (val.id.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(args)) || (val.email.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(args));
      return rVal;
    })

}
```

> html code

```
<tr *ngFor="let customer of users | customerEmailFilter:email;let i = index">
    <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
    <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

> ts file code

```
users=[{
    id:'123',
    email:'abc@gmail.com'
  },{
    id:'1234',
    email:'xyz@hotmail.com'
  },{
    id:'12345',
    email:'jsgsbh@kk.com'
  },{
    id:'123456',
    email:'test@gmail.com'
}]
```